# Как передать двумерный vector в метод класса?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Добрый день, вот есть у меня двумерный вектор 
`vector< vector<int> > arr`
Как мне его параметром передать в метод?

Comment: Это точно двумерный вектор?

Comment: Как надо, так и передайте. В чем проблема?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan двумерный массив на основе контейнера vector, разве нет?

Comment: @DavidRussel похож на зубчатый

Comment: Что-то странный код какой-то. Во первых, arr два раза объявляется (то есть, это даже компилиться не должно). Во вторых, судя по названию метода, вам просто надо найти значение максимального элемента вашего вектора векторов. Но вы, вместо того, чтобы использовать метод size(), возвращающий фактический размер вектора, почему-то ему resize делаете, У вас же там часть элементов может потеряться, или наоборот новых нулей добавиться. Это зачем?

Comment: И чему равны row и col? И, кстати, зачем нужна локальная копия arr? Почему не бегать по vect2?

Comment: Я просто не понимаю, зачем вы объединили две операции: 1) задание вектору векторов размерностей row и col, 2) поиск максимального элемента. Логично было бы видеть другую последовательность: 1) сначала вы задаете вектору векторов необходимые размерности, 2) заполняете вектор векторов какими-то числами, 3) ищете максимум. Причем, судя по названию, метод Max должен охватывать только 3-й этап. А первые 2 должны делаться где-то в другом месте.

Comment: @Voidificator изменил код, я в одном методе ввожу числа, вызываю метод нахождения максимального числа, но ничего не изменилось. ошибка та же

Comment: Что-то в модифицированном фрагменте vect2 вообще не участвует. Лучше приведите реальный код, который компилируете. А то так долго можно гадать.

Comment: @Voidificator все работает, скопировал по значению

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения эффективности, лучше по ссылке или указателю (если вектор не предполагается менять внутри метода, то по константной ссылке или указателю). Но можно и по значению (хотя в таком случае вектор будет копироваться, а это накладно).

Comment: Если собираетесь менять, то да. Если не собираетесь, то: const vector<vector<int> >* par

Comment: у меня при передачи всегда вот такая ошибка vector subscript out of range

Comment: Тогда приведите код, в котором проявляется эта ошибка. Что-то у вас там с индексами не то.